# using luajit installed with vcpkg

Tags: cmake, lua, vcpkg, luajit

I've a c++ project that uses `cmake` and `vcpkg`. I want to install and use [luajit](https://luajit.org/).

I've added it in my `vcpkg.json`:

```
{
  "name": "myproj",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": [
    "boost",
    "zeromq",
    "cppzmq",
    "yas",
    "luajit"
  ]
}
```

But then I'm not able to use it in a `CMakeFiles.txt`. If I try to add it:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.22)

project (myproj-luaclientlib)

add_definitions (-DMYPROJ_LUACLIENTLIB_EXPORTS)

find_package (LuaJIT REQUIRED)

include_directories (${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../)

set (PROJECT_SRC
  Author.cpp
)

add_library (${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${PROJECT_SRC})

target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC cxx_std_20)
```

`CMake` does not find it:

```
1> [CMake] CMake Error at P:/lib/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:855 (_find_package):
1> [CMake]   By not providing "FindLuaJIT.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
1> [CMake]   asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "LuaJIT", but
1> [CMake]   CMake did not find one.
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "LuaJIT" with any
1> [CMake]   of the following names:
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     LuaJITConfig.cmake
1> [CMake]     luajit-config.cmake
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   Add the installation prefix of "LuaJIT" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
1> [CMake]   "LuaJIT_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "LuaJIT"
1> [CMake]   provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
1> [CMake]   installed.
1> [CMake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
1> [CMake]   src/myproj/LuaClientLib/CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)
```

Other libraries works well.

What I'm doing wrong? What should I do in order to use `luajit` in my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LuaJIT does not have a `-config.cmake`. However, it installs a `*.pc` file so you can just use `FindPkgConfig`. So add `pkgconf` as a host dependency in your manifest and do:

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)  
pkg_check_modules(LuaJIT REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET luajit)
target_link_libraries(<your_target> PRIVATE PkgConfig::LuaJIT)
```